# Error while viewing page in browser.

Tags: asp.net

What is happening to my system? Tried to view my page in browser, but I am getting this error

```
Server Error in '/MCR' Application.  
The resource cannot be found.  
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,  
had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is  spelled correctly. 


Requested URL: /MCR/login.aspx  

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

Can someone help me with this? I don't even have login.aspx page. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well you have either a redirect on the page you are trying to view that goes to Login.aspx or you have set a default page to Login.aspx, which as you say doesn't exist.

Check through your project for any reference to Login.aspx and change it to the page you want as the default page.